# How to pass custom object in Post method of Restfull webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a requirement to recive some field value at webservice end which is passed by client in a custom object through Post call but its causes error like -

```
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/html;charset="utf-8" and type null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:522)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:513)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:414)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:337)
    at com.rest.jso.mainclient.RestJsonClient.processPOSTRequest(RestJsonClient.java:49)
    at com.rest.jso.mainclient.RestJsonClient.main(RestJsonClient.java:33)
```

My webservice looks like -

```
@POST
    @Path("/update/{user}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response updateRecord(@PathParam("user")String user) {

        User result = null;
        //User result = new User();
        try {
            result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(user, User.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result.setName("Ram");
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
```

My client to comsume the Rest service is -

```
public static void processPOSTRequest() /*throws ResponseStatusNotOKException*/{
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setName("My");
        newUser.setId(22L);
        newUser.setAddress("nagar");

        ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/JsonRestExample/userService/update");
        clientRequest.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE);
        ClientResponse<User> clientResponse = null;
        try {
            clientResponse = clientRequest.post(User.class);

        if(clientResponse != null && clientResponse.getResponseStatus().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            //User responseResult = clientResponse.getEntity();
            String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(clientResponse.getEntity());
            System.out.println(json);
            //System.out.println("updated address-> "+responseResult.getAddress()+"id=> "+responseResult.getId()+"Name=> "+responseResult.getName());
        }else{
            throw new ResponseStatusNotOKException("Response status is not OK.");
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm searching for the root cause but still clue less .Any Idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you are posting anything? In your code you define a newUser, but you never attach it to the post request.

Answer (score 0):

you can try post data by `xml` format, like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response updateRecord(String requestXml) {

    User result = null;
    //User result = new User();
    try {
        result = fromXml(requestXml, User.class);      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    result.setName("Ram");
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
```

while send http request,u need to convert `User` class to xml String,and then POST it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't define your request's body content. 
In your client you should do :

```
clientRequest.body("application/json", input);
```

Where input is your newUser encoded in JSON. After this only you should call

```
 clientResponse = clientRequest.post(User.class);
```